# Default source and target in SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Quite regularly I am importing data from XLS files into SQL Server database using standard Import and Export Wizard. 
(Right-click on my database in object explorer -> "Tasks" -> "Import Data")

I would like to find way to setup a default data source.

This is what I see every time I start a wizard:

[image]

I want it to be like this every time I run wizard:

[image]

The same story with destination.

I was trying to find place in settings and the only place I found is this one:

[image]

I tried to open *.vssettings file with Notepad but cant find any reference to location/destination there.

Maybe there are some hidden settings which can be changed in windows registry?

I hope that this can be changed as on my previous computer default source/destination settings were differently.

Answer (score -2):

The import/export wizard populate the excel only if the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 or Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.* is installed.
To enable the excel in the drop list, you can download Microsofr.ACE.OLEDB from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 and install it.

Comment: excel is installed and is available in drop down. the only thing I want is to make it preselected by default